# Perl issue with DateTime::Format::ISO8601 tracked to issue with Params::Validate?

Tags: linux, perl, cpan

Hope someone can shed some light on this...

I, and many other developers in the team have a large scale in house perl app running.  Despite this all working fine, across everyones laptops (linux and mac's), I can't for the life of me get this run on my big PC at home.

I've installed all the dependencies via cpan, but i'm getting the following in the apache error logs when visiting the site:

```
The 'regex' parameter ("(?x-ism:^ (\d{4}) (\d\d) (\d\d) $)") to DateTime::Format::Builder::Parser::create_single_parser was an 'unknown', which is not one of the allowed types: scalarref
 at /usr/local/lib/perl/5.12.4/Params/ValidatePP.pm line 651
    Params::Validate::__ANON__('The \'regex\' parameter ("(?x-ism:^ (\d{4}) (\d\d) (\d\d) $)"...') called at /usr/local/lib/perl/5.12.4/Params/ValidatePP.pm line 491
    Params::Validate::_validate_one_param('Regexp=REGEXP(0x7f8a3aad06e8)', 'HASH(0x7f8a3aaea840)', 'HASH(0x7f8a3aa75aa8)', 'The \'regex\' parameter ("(?x-ism:^ (\d{4}) (\d\d) (\d\d) $)")') called at /usr/local/lib/perl/5.12.4/Params/ValidatePP.pm line 353
    Params::Validate::validate('ARRAY(0x7f8a3aa33808)', 'HASH(0x7f8a3aa32db8)') called at /usr/local/share/perl/5.12.4/DateTime/Format/Builder/Parser.pm line 312
    DateTime::Format::Builder::Parser::create_single_parser(undef, 'params', 'ARRAY(0x7f8a3aad0640)', 'length', 8, 'regex', 'Regexp=REGEXP(0x7f8a3aad06e8)') called at /usr/local/share/perl/5.12.4/DateTime/Format/Builder/Parser.pm line 504
    DateTime::Format::Builder::Parser::sort_parsers('DateTime::Format::Builder::Parser', 'HASH(0x7f8a3aa4e2b8)', 'ARRAY(0x7f8a3aa3f148)') called at /usr/local/share/perl/5.12.4/DateTime/Format/Builder/Parser.pm line 398
    DateTime::Format::Builder::Parser::create_multiple_parsers('DateTime::Format::Builder::Parser', 'HASH(0x7f8a3aa4e2b8)', 'HASH(0x7f8a3aad06b8)', 'HASH(0x7f8a3aad0808)', 'HASH(0x7f8a3aad0910)', 'HASH(0x7f8a3aad0a00)', 'HASH(0x7f8a3aad0b08)', 'HASH(0x7f8a3aad0cb8)', 'HASH(0x7f8a3aad0e50)', ...) called at /usr/local/share/perl/5.12.4/DateTime/Format/Builder/Parser.pm line 603
    DateTime::Format::Builder::Parser::create_parser('DateTime::Format::Builder::Parser', 'ARRAY(0x7f8a3a72fc88)', 'HASH(0x7f8a3aad06b8)', 'HASH(0x7f8a3aad0808)', 'HASH(0x7f8a3aad0910)', 'HASH(0x7f8a3aad0a00)', 'HASH(0x7f8a3aad0b08)', 'HASH(0x7f8a3aad0cb8)', 'HASH(0x7f8a3aad0e50)', ...) called at /usr/local/share/perl/5.12.4/DateTime/Format/Builder.pm line 158
    DateTime::Format::Builder::create_parser('DateTime::Format::Builder', 'ARRAY(0x7f8a3aae5450)') called at /usr/local/share/perl/5.12.4/DateTime/Format/Builder.pm line 177
    DateTime::Format::Builder::create_end_parser('DateTime::Format::Builder', 'ARRAY(0x7f8a3aae5450)') called at /usr/local/share/perl/5.12.4/DateTime/Format/Builder.pm line 106
    DateTime::Format::Builder::create_class(undef, 'parsers', 'HASH(0x7f8a3aae8f18)') called at /usr/local/share/perl/5.12.4/DateTime/Format/ISO8601.pm line 175
```

I've stuck some noddy `print STDERR`'s directly in the `ValidatePP.pm` so if you are looking at the line numbers and they are slightly out, but basically in `ValidatePP.pm` it is getting to the following code block in `sub _get_type`:

```
 # I really hope this never happens.
 return UNKNOWN;
```

If it helps, running a perl -v returns the following version on this PC

> This is perl 5, version 12, subversion 4 (v5.12.4) built for
>   x86_64-linux-gnu-thread-multi

Anybody?

UPDATE:

If it helps, the subroutine `_get_type` is basically deciding (using `UNIVERSAL::isa`) that `regex: !!perl/regexp (?x-ism:^ (\d{4}) (\d\d) (\d\d) $)` is not one if the following:

```
my %isas = (
        'ARRAY'  => ARRAYREF,
        'HASH'   => HASHREF,
        'CODE'   => CODEREF,
        'GLOB'   => GLOBREF,
        'SCALAR' => SCALARREF,
    );
```

Comment: It would help if you provided code that produces the problem.

Comment: The code base is huge, but boils down to "USE DateTime::Format::ISO8601" which throws the error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, are you using the latest version of [Params::Validate](https://metacpan.org/release/DROLSKY/Params-Validate-1.03/) (and all the other modules)?
According to the [changelog](https://metacpan.org/source/DROLSKY/Params-Validate-1.03/Changes) there were some bugs in P::V 1.01:

> 1.02    2012-02-06
>
> - The previous release never loaded the XS implementation, even if it had been
>     compiled.
> - With newer versions of Perl, the pure Perl implementation treated regexp
>     objects differently than the XS implementation. They should be treated as
>     belonging to the SCALARREF type for backwards compatibility.
> - These two bugs combined managed to break the test suites of a number of
>     modules on CPAN. This release should fix them.

Comment: Think you might be right - certainly sounds like my issue, and the newer version was only released a few days ago - i'll check my version later today and try to upgrade it - hopefully you are right!

Comment: Thanks yibe, upgrading that module has fixed it.  I feel very silly now :(